Apache NiFi Truststore Certificated Authentication
I am trying to allow certificate authentication for my NiFi instance, to simplify login over single-sign-on.
I successfully setup a truststore with my CA and updated the value of nifi.security.truststore, which works and authenticates all users without requiring a single-sign-on, however I wanted more control than just allowing my entire CA.
Interestingly this worked, despite leaving the default settings for nifi.security.user.authorizer and nifi.security.user.login.dentity.provider.
I then tried to setup a truststore with just my direct colleague and I's certificates, intentionally with no CA or intermediaries included. This did not seem to work, and I am presented with the single-sign-in screen once again.
Any tips/advice on how to achieve this?
Is it possible for me to trust the entire CA in a truststore, but then whitelist specific CNs as the only approved users?
I am using NiFi 1.19.1
